# Java - Creating a menu method - Lots of trouble

Tags: loops, error-handling, while-loop, menu, user-input

I am tasked with making a word game that has 2 options, plus an exit option. I must make a separate method for each option and am currently working on the method that displays the menu options and gets the users input, then returns that input to the called methods.

This is where I'm at so far. My goal with this code is to get a user to select option 1, 2 or 3 with error checking to force the user to input 1, 2 or 3. Current problems are that inputting option 1, 2 or 3, will print the statement, followed by an extra print statement from both option 1, 2 and 3. Inputting a number outside of 1, 2 and 3 doesn't print the error statement, but does allow the user to input again. Also inputting anything other than a number will endlessly run the loop.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Small_Programming_Assignment {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getSelection();
        substringProblem();
        pointsProblem();
        
    }
    public static void getSelection() {
        int selection = -1;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Word Games program menu.");
        System.out.println("Select from one of the following options.");
        System.out.println("1. Substring problem.");
        System.out.println("2. Points problem.");
        System.out.println("3. Exit.");
        System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
        selection = scanner.nextInt();
        
        while (selection < 1 || selection > 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
            if(scanner.hasNextInt())
                selection = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        switch(selection) {
            case 1:
                substringProblem();
                break;
            case 2:
                pointsProblem();
                break;
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Goodbye");
                break;
            default: 
                System.out.println("Invalid option. Try again. ");
        }
        
    }
    public static void substringProblem() {
        System.out.println("Game 1");
    }
    public static void pointsProblem() {
        System.out.println("Game 2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

2 problems.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getSelection();
//        substringProblem();
//        pointsProblem();
    }

    public static void getSelection() {
        int selection = -1;
//        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Word Games program menu.");
        System.out.println("Select from one of the following options.");
        System.out.println("1. Substring problem.");
        System.out.println("2. Points problem.");
        System.out.println("3. Exit.");
        System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
//        selection = scanner.nextInt();

        boolean running = true;
        
        // make sure running until the input is 3
        while (running) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            selection = scanner.nextInt();
            while (selection < 1 || selection > 3) {
                System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
                if(scanner.hasNextInt())
                    selection = scanner.nextInt();
            }
            switch(selection) {
                case 1:
                    substringProblem();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    pointsProblem();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    // stop
                    running = false;
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid option. Try again. ");
            }
        }


    }
```